# How to combine all lines in a text file between each empty line

Tags: python

I have a text file that looks like this

```
a
b
c

d
e
f
```

I want to combine these on each empty line so that it looks like this

```
abc def
```

Ive tried this

```
result = " ".join(line.strip() for line in file)
```

which works but I only want there to be a space if there was an empty line found is this possible?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. It seems like you want "either the content of the line, or a single space if it's empty".

Answer (score 4):

This can be accomplished by reading the entire file and replacing newline chars (`\n`). For example:

```py
with open("/path/to/file") as f:
    result = f.read().replace("\n\n", " ").replace("\n", "")

print(result)  # abc def
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
result = ""
with open('path\to\file', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        val = line.strip()
        # Check if string is not empty string
        if val:
            result += val
        # Add a space
        else:
            result += " "
```

If you wanted to do it as a one line:

```
result = "".join(line.strip() if line.strip() else " " for line in file)
```

`result`:

```
'abc def'
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to do something a little different than `str.strip` - return the stripped string or a space if the result is empty - so write your own function that does that. Now you have a function that does exactly what you want and you don't need to add your own spaces.

```
def stripper(line):
    line = line.strip()
    return line if line else " "

with open("test.txt") as file:
    result = "".join(stripper(line) for line in file)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

For "fun" we can approach this from a functional standpoint with [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html).

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> lines = ['a', 'b', 'c', '', 'd', 'e', 'f']
>>> lines2 = reduce(
...   (lambda i, x: [[x]] if i == [] else \
...                 [*i, []] if x.strip() == '' else \
...                 [*i[:-1], i[-1]+[x]]),
...   lines, 
...   []
... )
>>> lines2
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
>>> ' '.join(map(''.join, lines2))
'abc def'
```